# Spring-Boot Access object created in main from RequestMapping

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring-boot for implementing a REST server. Inside a function for request mapping, I have to create an object which is heavyweight, so for every REST call I have do it and it is slowing things down. Is it possible to create the object in main and access from the function?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* I want to initialize the object here */
        SpringApplication.run(MyClass.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/go/to/user/summary")
    public Users[] getUsers(@RequestParam(value="length", defaultValue="10") int length) {

/* I want to use the object here */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a bean in `MyClass` and then consume that bean in `MyController`. Spring will only create a single instance of the bean so you'll avoid the cost of creating it multiple times. Something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        SpringApplication.run(MyClass.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Heavyweight heavyweight() {
        // Initialize and return heavyweight object here 
    }

}

@RestController
public class MyController {

    private final Heavyweight heavyweight;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(Heavyweight heavyweight) {
        this.heavyweight = heavyweight;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/go/to/user/summary")
    public Users[] getUsers(@RequestParam(value="length", defaultValue="10") int length) {
        // Use heavyweight here
        this.heavyweight.foo();

        // ...

        return users;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think You can use [@Service](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html) for this approach. Service class is [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) so if You create object inside it on startup application then You can use it requests in Your controllers class.

Example service:

```
@Service
public class MyService{
    private MyLargeObject largeObject;

    public MyLargeObject set(MyLargeObject largeObject){
        this.largeObject = largeObject;
    }

    public MyLargeObject get(){
        return largeObject;
    }
}
```

Example controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyController{

    @Inject
    private MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping("/go/to/user/summary")
    public Users[] getUsers(@RequestParam(value="length", defaultValue="10") int length) {

       MyLargeObject o = myService.get();
    }
}
```

**EDIT1:**

If You want init Your largeObject directly in service You can use [@PostConstruct](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) annotation. For example:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // initialization Your object here
}
```

Comment: I tried to use this approach but I get `largeObject` as `null` when I call the `get()` method. I created the `myService` object in the `main()`, both before and after `SpringApplication.run(MyClass.class, args);` line.

Comment: probably You are never seeting this object. See my EDIT1

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try.